# Android: Asynch Thread for Method

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading, asynchronous

Ive realised that in order for a part of my application to work i may need to run it on a separate thread. After this my options seemed to be Asynch and Threads and i think Asynch seems the better choice as i have little experience in working with threads. I am trying to run petrolPriceString on a separate thread but i dont have the knowledge to do this. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Edit: the addtion of my entire class

```
package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PetrolPriceActivity extends Menu 
{
    private TextView response;
    private TextView errorText;
    private String result;
    private String petrolPriceURL;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(extras!=null){
        petrolPriceURL =extras.getString("URLString");
        }
        // Get the TextView object on which to display the results
        response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
        response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
        try
        {
            // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
            result =  petrolPriceString(petrolPriceURL);

            // Do some processing of the data to get the individual parts of the RSS stream
            // At some point put this processing into a separate thread of execution
            // Display the string in the TextView object just to demonstrate this capability
            // This will need to be removed at some point
            response.setText(result);
        }
        catch(IOException ae)
        {
            // Handle error
            response.setText("Error");
            // Add error info to log for diagnostics
            errorText.setText(ae.toString());
        } 

    }

    // End of onCreate

    // Method to handle the reading of the data from the RSS stream
    private static String petrolPriceString(String urlString)throws IOException
    {
        String result = "";
        InputStream anInStream = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        // Check that the connection can be opened
        if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try
        {
            // Open connection
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            // Check that connection is Ok
            if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                // Connection is OK so open a reader 
                anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                String line = new String();
                while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                {
                    result = result + "\n" + line;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }

        // Return result as a string for further processing
        return result;
    }
    // End of petrolPriceString
 // End of Activity class
}
```

My application at the moment is error free however the output i am getting isnt what i want so i believe a separate thread is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AsyncTask is useful for doing slow work in the background (like network interaction) and following it up with a final bit of processing/interaction on the main/UI thread. If I am understanding your request correctly, you can try something like this:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // we do this part in the background on another thread
        return petrolPriceString(params[0]);
    }
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // result is the value returned from our call to petrolPriceString
        // anything we put in here is done on the main/UI thread
    }
}.execute(urlString);
```

If you want to catch the exception thrown by petrolPriceString, and execute some logic accordingly, one possible solution is to save it as a local member within the AsyncTask. Something like the following...

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>() {
    IOException exception = null;
    @Override protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            return petrolPriceString(params[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exception = e;
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (exception != null) {
            // handle our exception
        } else {
            // handle our result
        }
    }
}.execute(urlString);
```

Comment: great yes i think this is exactly what im looking for. Could i use this AsyncTask method in the same activity as my petrolPriceString and it would still run on a separate thread?

Comment: Yes, the `doInBackground` part will be executed on a separate thread from a pool that Android sets up for you.

Comment: on the case of onPostExecute i have code elsewhere in my try catch block with handles the aftermath of petrolPriceString how would this change with this added onPostExcute method?

Comment: I think the easiest solution in that case is to catch the exception inside the AsyncTask itself. I have updated my answer with an example of how this can be accomplished. Hopefully this works for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: great thanks. the doinbackground is a long rather than a string. why is this?

Comment: hi ive added my entire PetrolPriceActivity class so i can ask this. In my onCreate method i reference the I/O exception does this matter?

Comment: As long as you move the exception handling code into the onPostExecute call it will work fine. Just be aware that doing this means that onCreate is likely to finish while the background thread is still working. That means the view will be shown to the user _before_ your code has finished running and setting the text on your TextView. The result is that the user might see an empty TextView for a few seconds _and then_ the text will appear. If your background task is very fast this is no big deal. If your background task is slow, consider displaying a loading dialog while the user waits.